# Battery drain caused by Android System (job.deadline and motion sensor)

Tags: battery, battery-life

Environment: Redmi Note 10 Pro, Android 13, MIUI 14.

Since a pair of days I'm facing a battery drain never seen before: by a first look the culprit seems to be Android System:

[image: battery usage report]

The fact is that the phone loose 1% every hour without doing nothing, just left it alone without using it.
I tried to clear Play Service data and cache, as well PlayStore data and cache, but I am unable to find the real culprit.

I link the logs from Better Battery Stats:

[Better Battery Stats Logs](https://pastebin.com/mm5m4Czx)

Here is reported that in 2h and 40s has lost only 1% (0.5%/h) but immediately after the save of the log, the battery dropped to 71%.

What can I do to avoid this battery drain? How to find the culprit?

**EDIT:**
In 3C Task Manager, I noticed the following:
Since the issue occurred, I noticed that Play Store and Play Service are always present/active; three days ago they were not present in the list of active processes.

**EDIT 2:**

I have a good news: I pinpointed the culprit to Google Play Services; I went to apkmirror and I downloaded `Google Play services 23.13.12 beta` and installed it. After two hours of idle the battery has been on 0% of usage.
I will update again this question if will be fine in the next days.

**EDIT 3:**

First of all, I forgot to mention that in EDIT 2, without battery drain, I was on Wi-Fi.
Today I have been outside, on mobile data, 4G, with, for the most of the time, a good signal strenght.
This time Android System has been less hungry:

[image: battery stats]

I've lost 7% of battery in 4 hours: I've done 2 phone calls, received an email and checked the time few times.
Anyway, Android System, is still the  battery drainer

**EDIT 4:**

Finally i recorded a log of when the battery drain occurred: in this case is of 1.6%/h. I noticed that mainly occurs when I walk/move, like if was caused by the motion sensor. I attach the log of better battery stats:

[battery drain log](https://pastebin.com/N7wb945g)

As you can read in the Better Battery States log, when the battery drain occurs, Android System wakeups a lot:

```
android (): Wakeups: 123 (50.2 / h)
  Alarms: 0, Intent: TIME_TICK
  Alarms: 82, Intent: *job.deadline*
  Alarms: 0, Intent: upload_dark_mode_switch
  Alarms: 0, Intent: *job.delay*
  Alarms: 22, Intent: DeviceIdleController.motion_registration
```

But if I leave the phone on the table, untouched/not used, the battery drain doesn't occurs: in this case is 0.0%/h:

[NO battery drain](https://pastebin.com/hyp3m2rh):

```
android (): Wakeups: 25 (13.6 / h)
  Alarms: 0, Intent: TIME_TICK
  Alarms: 0, Intent: com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_POLL
  Alarms: 0, Intent: *job.cleanup*
  Alarms: 18, Intent: *job.deadline*
  Alarms: 0, Intent: *job.delay*
  Alarms: 1, Intent: DeviceIdleController.motion_registration
```

Comment: A 2 years old phone is due to have a noticeable reduction on battery autonomy.

Comment: @ChanganAuto As stated, the issue occurs since two days; two days ago I had a perfect battery life.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have a 6 years old Xiaomi low-range phone running Android 11 and its battery still lasts a day with normal use.

Comment: @Dave you may want to try my app [WhatsRunning](https://github.com/mirfatif/WhatsRunning). It may help identify the root cause. Related: [Which Android apps are draining battery?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/android_apps_drain_battery). Disclaimer: both links belong to me.