# Manually updated Google Play Services. Will it continue to autoupdate iteself?

Tags: updates, google-play-services, application-autoupdate

Due to an [investigation of battery drain](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/251026/battery-drain-caused-by-android-system), I manually updated Google Play Services from ApkMirror (to V. [23.13.12 beta](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-23-13-12-release/)).

If I'm not wrong, I recall that Google Play Services update itself when new stable version is out (or is updated with Play Store?); will it continue to update also if I updated it manually? If not, what to do, to have it regularly updated?

Comment: If your phone came with pre-installed Google apps and services then it should make a difference if you manually update it or if the updates were automatically downloaded and applied by the Google services itself.

Comment: @Robert Yes: my phone came with pre-installed Google apps and services. So to summarize: will, Google Play Services, autoupdate itself also if I updated it manually?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't autoupdate (there was and update of Google Play Service yesterday 3 April 2023, on Play Store).
I had to uninstall update on Google Play Service, then it autoupdate itself.